# Creating a function that will handle objects with common properties

Tags: c#, .net, function, properties, casting

Take this as an example

I have trimmed this example for readability and you may not find the use of this concept here.

```
class Teacher()
{
 public Name {get; set;}
 public Salt {get; set;}
 public Department{get; set;}
}

class Student()
{
 public Name {get; set;}
        public Salt {get; set;}
 public Section{get; set;}
}

public string GetEncryptedName(object Person)
{
 //return encrypted name based on Name and Salt property
 return encrypt(object.Salt,object.Name)
}
```

callig the function

```
GetEncryptedName(Teacher)
GetEncryptedName(Student)
```

How do you implement this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement a common interface / base class in both Teacher and Student:

```
interface IPerson {
    string Name {get;set;}
    string Salt {get;set;}
}

class Teacher : IPerson...

class Student : IPerson...

public string GetEncryptedName(IPerson person)
{
 //return encrypted name based on Name and Salt property
 return encrypt(person.Salt,person.Name)
}
```

That way you can call GetEncryptedName when any object that implements the IPerson interface and is guaranteed to implement the Name and Salt properties

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. Have both `Teacher` and `Student` inherit from a base class, let's call it `Person`.  This `Person` class will have two properties, `Name` and `Salt`, and it can also have a public method called `GetEncryptedName()`, which will keep your implementation organized in a single place.

Answer (score 1):

You need an Interface that both classes implement. Then you can pass the GetEncryptedName() method an interface.

```
interface IPerson
{
 string Name {get; set;}
 string Salt {get; set;}
 string Section {get; set;}
}

class Teacher : IPerson
{
 public Name {get; set;}
 public Salt {get; set;}
 public Section{get; set;}
 public Department{get; set;}
}

class Student : IPerson
{
 public Name {get; set;}
 public Salt {get; set;}
 public Section{get; set;}
}

public string GetEncryptedName(IPerson person)
{
 //return encrypted name based on Name and Salt property
 return encrypt(person.Salt,person.Name)
}
```

Here is the MSDN reference to interfaces: [interface (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Just note that this would not compile.... Teacher would need to implement the Section property from the IPerson

Answer (score 0):

you could define an interface that both the Teacher and Student clases implement. Something like:
That is what I would do.

```
interface IEncryptionInfoProvider
{
    Name {get; set;}
    Salt {get; set;}
}
```

If you do not wish to define this interface, you would have to use reflection to get the values of the properties by name.
There are plenty of examples, info on the web on this topic.
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/reflection/article.php/c4257